# Limit with natural logarithm

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Is it true that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)^a}{\ln(\ln(x))^{a+b}}=+\infty$$
for any $a>0$ and $b \geq 1$? I believe this to be true but am having a hard time grasping it since $\ln(x)$ grows so slowly.

Comment: Begin by the substitution $ t=\ln(x)$.

Comment: 1)  $\frac {\ln(x)^a}{\ln(\ln(x))^{a+b}}=\ln[x^a - \ln x^{a+b}]$,  or 2) let $t=\ln(x)$ then we have $\frac {t^a}{\ln t^{a+b}}$ or 3) "am having a hard time grasping it since ln(x) grows so slowly."  $\ln x$ grows slow compared to $x$ so $\ln (\ln x)$ will grow even slower.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\ln(x)$

$$L=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^a}{\ln^{a+b}(t)}
=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left( \frac{t^{\frac{a}{a+b}}}{\ln(t)}\right)^{a+b}
=\left(\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^{\frac{a}{a+b}}}{\ln(t)}\right)^{a+b}
=\left(\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^{k}}{\ln(t)}\right)^{a+b}$$

where $0<k=\frac{a}{a+b}<1$, since:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^{k}}{\ln(t)}=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{k\cdot t^{k-1}}{1/t}=\lim_{t\to\infty} k\cdot t^k\to\infty$$

So we have $L\to\infty$